# Variable expansion not working inside Sed search and replace

Tags: sed

`OS=GNU Linux`

**Input File**

```
gene_id "STRG.50";
gene_id "STRG.52";
gene_id "STRG.59";
```

**Template for Replacement**

```
STRG.50  AT1G27500
STRG.52  AT2G37985
STRG.59  AT2G33392
```

**Bash**

```
while read bef aft
do
  echo $bef
  echo $aft
  sed -i "s/$bef\";/$aft\";/g" input.txt
done < template
```

This does not work.  Echo lines work correctly, but the input file remains unchanged and sed hangs indefinitely after all echo statements have finished.

Comment: After you have this working, you should improve this to do all the changes in a single invocation of sed, rather than one sed for each line of the template.

Comment: Put `set -x` before the `sed` line and `set +x` after the `sed` line; this will show you exactly what command the shell is trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works:

```
tuhin@tuhin-virtualvbox:temp$ cat input.txt 
gene_id "STRG.50";
gene_id "STRG.52";
gene_id "STRG.59";
tuhin@tuhin-virtualvbox:temp$ cat template 
STRG.50  AT1G27500
STRG.52  AT2G37985
STRG.59  AT2G33392
tuhin@tuhin-virtualvbox:temp$ while read bef aft; do   echo $bef;   echo $aft;   sed -i "s/$bef\";/$aft\";/g" input.txt; done < template 
STRG.50
AT1G27500
STRG.52
AT2G37985
STRG.59
AT2G33392
tuhin@tuhin-virtualvbox:temp$ cat input.txt 
gene_id "AT1G27500";
gene_id "AT2G37985";
gene_id "AT2G33392";
tuhin@tuhin-virtualvbox:temp$
```

Comment: Interesting.  What system are you on?

Comment: Works for me too....output is exactly as per @Tuhin

Comment: @cryptic0 ubuntu in virtual box (on windows). Here is the output of `lsb_release -a`:
```No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic```